# Django Rendering Template Included in a Template

Tags: python, django

Basically I have a base template, and the base template is including another template, let's say, latest update. So the structure is like this:

```
-base.html
     |---------latest_update.html
```

So, I know how to include a simple template, like the template without any data processing (doesn't require interaction with any application view.py). However, how could I attach the included template into a django application view.py so that I could at least show updated data periodically?

I am not exactly sure terms for this, feel free to change the title.

Edit: This question is a bit cloudy, as I don't know how to put the terminology correctly. So, I have this included template. Every page will have it. So, from my limited knowledge, that means I have to render it manually for every page that hits `view.py`. Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: Are you just talking about rending the template inside a view with a context? I dont really understand your terminology

Comment: @jdi That is the hardest thing lol, the terminology. I know how to render a template inside a view with context. But since this included template , I am quite unclear how to render it. If I were to render it normally, that means I have to render it every function in views.py? ( since basically every page has the latest_update)

Comment: Or is it inclusion tag you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django templatetags. Define a file named `latest_update_tags` under your Django app `templatetags` directory and write code like this to define a `latest_update` templatetags:

```
from django import template

from app.models import UpdateObject

register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag("latest_update.html")
def latest_update():
  update_objects = UpdateObject.all().[:10]
  return {"update_objects": update_objects}
```

And then in your `base.html` use it like this:

```
{% load latest_update_tags %}
......
{% latest_update %}
```